# How to use ngClass with table in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I have a table, where I want to declare ngClass (first row)

```
<table [ngClass]="{'before_forth': pageNumber < 4, 'forth': pageNumber = 4}">
    <tr id="words" *ngFor="let item of itemsSource3; let i = index;">
      <td *ngFor="let item2 of helper[i]; let j = index;">
        <input class="resizedTextbox" name="{{i}}{{j}}"
            [(ngModel)]="helper[i][j].value" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange(f,i)"/>
      </td>
    {{item}}
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my CSS is

```
table.forth.td:nth-child(2){background-color: green}
table.forth.td:nth-child(5){background-color: green}


table.before_forth.td:nth-child(2){background-color: red}
table.before_forth.td:nth-child(5){background-color: red}
```

So, what I would like to do is to set the colour, which depends on the number of page (in my component I use this method

```
this.pageNumber = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['page'];
```

and it worked fine in other cases ( I use it oft)

I guess the problem is in css, in this piece of code `table.forth.td:nth-child`, could you please tell me what would be the right way to access class within the table?

Comment: `table.forth.td` - means a `table` which have a class `forth` and another class `td`, I think you want this: `table.forth  td:nth-child()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pageNumber === 4` and not `pageNumber = 4`, because then you are just assigning the variable:

```
<table [ngClass]="{'before_forth': pageNumber < 4, 'forth': pageNumber === 4}">
```

The second problem is the css rule, you are using a `.td` class in there, even though it's nowhere used in the html. My guess is that you want to target the `<td>` element inside the table:

```
table.forth td:nth-child(2){background-color: green}
table.forth td:nth-child(5){background-color: green}


table.before_forth td:nth-child(2){background-color: red}
table.before_forth td:nth-child(5){background-color: red}
```

The third problem is the usage of `{{item}}` outside the `<td>` tag. This is invalid `html` and will result in unwanted behaviour, you should move this inside the `td`

Also, don't use `id` inside in combination with `*ngFor`. An element with an id is supposed to be unique throughout the entire page. Actually, it's better not to use id at all if you have no special use for it:

```
<table [class.before_forth]="pageNumber < 4" [class.forth]="pageNumber === 4">
  <tr *ngFor="let item of itemsSource3; let i = index;">
    <td *ngFor="let item2 of helper[i]; let j = index;">
      <input class="resizedTextbox" name="{{i}}{{j}}" [(ngModel)]="helper[i}[j].value" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange(f,i)">
      {{item}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The last point is, the proper spelling of `4th` is *fourth* and not *forth*, but that's just an fyi ;)